# Open standard dialogs in Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension and would like to open the **Connect to Team Foundation Server** standard dialog on click.

I was able to do so utilizing the [`DTE2.ExecuteCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.dte2.executecommand.aspx) method like `DTE2.ExecuteCommand("Team.ConnecttoTeamFoundationServer")` but I feel that there must be a better way to do that then using Visual Studio macros.

Any help is most appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Team Project Picker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.teamprojectpicker.aspx) class of `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` assembly. This [blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/06/18/tfs-2010-sdk-connecting-to-tfs-2010-programmaticallyndashpart-1.aspx) gives the complete detail on how to use the same. I am pasting below, the sample code from the above blog post which will help you to show the dialog.

```
private static TfsTeamProjectCollection _tfs;
private static ProjectInfo _selectedTeamProject;

// Connect to TFS Using Team Project Picker
public static void ConnectToTfsUsingTeamProjectPicker()
{
     // The  user is allowed to select only one project
     var tfsPp = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.SingleProject, false);

     tfsPp.ShowDialog();

     // The TFS project collection
     _tfs = tfsPp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection;

     if (tfsPp.SelectedProjects.Any())
     {
          //  The selected Team Project
          _selectedTeamProject = tfsPp.SelectedProjects[0];
     }
 }
```